# How to filter out in arrays to not display strings from databse?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php require_once("Database.php"); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM list ";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $blacklist = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    // BLACKLISTS 
    if (in_array($name, $blacklist)) {
        die("Sorry! $name is not found");
    }
    else {
        $api1 = file_get_contents("API");
        echo "$name's ip is: $api1";        
    }

}
?>
```

So I've been at this for hours and I have decided that I need help. So what I am trying to do is simply us the if statement to create a blacklist using the strings or names I have saved in my database. The problem is it only black lists the first id or name and it wont accept or acknowledge the other names in my database. I was wondering if anyone maybe could give me a suggestion as to how I could write the code so I use all the names in said database instead of only the first one.

Also tried this and i still dont get the die statement.

```
<?php require_once("Database.php"); ?>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM list WHERE names = ?';
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $name);
     mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    if ($count) die("Sorry! $name is not found");// ITS BLACKLISTED
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }  else {
        $api1 = file_get_contents("api");
        echo "$name's ip is: $api1";        
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Try to `var_dump($blacklist)` to see if the array structure is correct.

Comment: @pbaldauf `array (size=2)
  0 => string 'adam.a932' (length=9)
  'names' => string 'adam.a932' (length=9)` is what i got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
<?php require_once("Database.php"); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username = '$name' ";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $blacklist = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    // BLACKLISTS 
    if (in_array($name, $blacklist)) {
        die("Sorry! $name is not found");
    }
    else {
        $api1 = file_get_contents("API");
        echo "$name's ip is: $api1";        
    }

}
?>
```

So what i did is i added `WHERE username ='$name'` to `$sql` in order for it to accurately see what exactly i want to be extracted from the database. i disabled the error reporting because it was giving me a null parameter for the in array, ill enable it when i keep disabling, but disable it when i display it to the public.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are returning * which will return all fields from the table. You only want to return an array of names and check those.

Ideally you want an array from the list table that looks like this:

```
//['tom', 'jim', 'sam', 'bob']
```

I've just checked the docs for mysql_fetch_array [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and it returns a multidimensional array. You're probably getting something like this back:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'tom'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'jim'
    ]
]
```

In the array above you don't have a list of names therefore name is not in the array.

As @Ziumin mentions we need to get the "name" key out of the array so I've updated the in_array part below:

```
<?php require_once("Database.php"); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM list";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $blacklist = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    // BLACKLISTS 
    //get all the names from all the rows into one array
    $nameList = array_column($blacklist, 'name');
    //check that the posted name is in this list
    if (in_array($name, $nameList)) {
        die("Sorry! $name is not found");
    }
    else {
        $api1 = file_get_contents("API");
        echo "$name's ip is: $api1";        
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Replace `in_array($name, $blacklist)` with `in_array($name, array_column($blacklist, 'name'))` please. And i'll +1 your answer

Comment: @Ziumin That just breaks the code and ignores the first name now completely. Also changing the * to name did not work as well.

Comment: You should have php5.5 to use array_column. Or use https://github.com/ramsey/array_column for older php versions

Comment: @Ziumin a question do i need a primary key column for this to work?

Comment: @Adam No. You don't need it.

Comment: So i tried doing this and now i get this `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in C:\wamp\www\Api developement\skype.php on line 10` and still no die statement i think i'm doing something severely wrong.

Comment: @Adam that should be fixed now - we needed to get all the names into an array. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this question. As far as you have a database with blacklisted users, and you want to check if some username is blacklisted I suggest you to make this check without fetching all the blacklist table (which can be quite big).

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM list WHERE names = ?';
$name = $_POST['username'];
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $name);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
  mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
  if ($count) die("Sorry! $name is not found");// ITS BLACKLISTED
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  $api1 = file_get_contents("api");
  echo "$name's ip is: $api1";    
}
```

Comment: where does the $count variable come from?

Comment: It's first use of this variable. `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` just saves its reference, so `mysqli_stmt_fetch` will store result into. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: i tried this i get no errors, but i also get no results. now i know i must be doing something stupid...

Comment: I updated my answer. You dont need `else` here, because you have die in your `if` statement

Comment: Still doesent recognize the stored values as a blacklist.